# Javascript (Not defined error)

Tags: javascript

I started doing a HTML/Javascript code for a work and I had an error telling my function was not defined. Could someone please help me and tell me whats my error ?

Thank you.

## js

```
function genererPage() {
  var logo = document.createElement("img");
  logo.setAttribute("src", "Images/logo_js.png");
  logo.setAttribute("width", "175");
  logo.setAttribute("height", "110");
  logo.setAttribute("alt", "Logo de JavaScript");
  document.header.appendChild(logo);
}
```

## html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> TP1 - DÉPART - Créer dynamiquement une page web adaptive en HTML5
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="genererpage()"> Génére la page </button>
  <script>
    src = "Javascripts/fonctions.js "
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

## error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: genererpage is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (TP1_Depart.html:8)
```

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: Please don't post images of code, type (or copy) the text, and mention the line in which you get the error.

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TP1 - DÉPART - Créer dynamiquement une page web adaptive en HTML5</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <button onclick="genererpage()">Génére la page</button>
 <script> src="Javascripts/fonctions.js" </script>
 </body>
 
</html>

Comment: @Kevin It looks different from the code that is included in the image above.

Comment: the error is "Uncaught ReferenceError: genererpage is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (TP1_Depart.html:8)"

Comment: `genererpage` and `genererPage` are not the same.

Comment: @AndersonGreen the image is my js function

Comment: When asking questions it is recommended to have a **Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example**. You can see the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create one. You can add runnable code to your question using a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: like @Xufox said you call `onclick="genererpage()"` in html, but in js it's name is different, its called `genererPage()` with a capital `P`

Comment: I heard what you guys said but after fixing the capital P mistake I still have the "is "Uncaught ReferenceError: genererpage is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (TP1_Depart.html:8)" error

Comment: @Kevin Then you haven’t fixed the issue. Closely look at your code. Read the error message. It’s telling you the exact source of the error.

Comment: the js isn't properly linked then; you have `<script> src = "Javascripts/fonctions.js " </script>` make sure that you have the correct path and name to the `js` file and that you fix the `<script> src ="...."` typo to `<script src = "..."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure what line of code is meant to have the error in reality - as the line highlighted https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDzdI.jpg doesn't seem to be the problem. Here's your code again:

```
var logo = document.createElement("img");
logo.setAttribute("src", "Images/logo_js.jpg");
logo.setAttribute("width", "175");
logo.setAttribute("height", "110");
logo.setAttribute("alt", "logo de JavaScript");
document.header.appendChild(logo)
```

The problem line is the last line. It should be

```
document.head.appendChild(logo);
```

There may be other issues within your app - but that's the only problem line I can see in your code. It's also easier if you just output your code here on Stackoverflow than reference it within an image.

Comment: Tried fixing it your way but the error is still there.

Comment: The issue has already been spotted six minutes ago; read the comments above. This question is off-topic (simple typo) and should be deleted, not answered.

Comment: @Xufox issue spotted but not fixed, thank you.

Comment: @Xufox Ah. I didn't see the comments when I first landed on the page. He still would have had an error with the same line as it should be as per the specs - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/head. I apparently wasn't able to comment intially. Rookie Stackoverflow user here.